# How to use exchange rate from Currency Api in a field?

Tags: theming, entities

1. I've installed Currency Api Module + Yahoo! Finance currency converter and
2. made with "Currency Filter" a new field (using [Markup module](https://www.drupal.org/project/markup)) in my content named "latest_exchange_rate" with the value of latest USD-EUR exchange rate coming from Yahoo!Finance;
3. in the same content, there is a decimal field named "usd_value" filled with a value during content creation;
4. additionally I created also a Computed field named "eur_value" which is a multiplication = "latest_exchange_rate * usd_value";

The problem is that the computed field seems not able to read the value of "latest_exchange_rate" field, and the result is always 0.00.

I am not a coder, can you please help me to solve this problem?
If my approach is not correct, how can I use an exchange value from Currency API to make conversions between different currencies?

Thank you in advance for attention, Francesco in Cina

Comment: Hi @Francesco. Could you post your computed field's code? Is this in the compute or in the display function? And what is the data type of that field in the Database? Are you storing it even? Lots of questions :-)

Comment: Hi @Stefanos, this is what i've wrote in my computed code: `$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity-> usd_value['und'][0]['value'] * $entity-> latest_exchange_rate['und'][0]['value'];`

As mentioned, the "usd_value" is a decimal field, and "latest_exchange_rate" is a read only Markup field with inside  [currency:USD:EUR] (according to "Currency Filter" instructions came from Currency Module).

Thank you again for your kind reply.

Comment: Hey @Francesco, put this is your OP, it's better for other people that may try to help you. Thanks for the reply, will get back to you about this.

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/339734)   
and [this reference](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/currency/currency_api--currency_api.module/function/currency_api_convert/7), following  is my second attempt, in computed code I set: `$from = 'USD'; $to   = 'EUR'; $amt  = 1; $ret = currency_api_convert($from, $to, $amt); $entity_field[0]['value'] = $ret['value'].;` But again, still nothing is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much leaner version of your setup:

In order to get your node to always display the current converted usd_value to EUROs, you will need only one computed field (no markup field required). 
You just will need to place the following in the "Display Code (PHP)" textarea:

```
$conversion_factor = CurrencyYahooFinanceCurrencyExchanger::load('USD','EUR');
$node_usd_value = $entity->field_usd_value[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$euro_value_live = $conversion_factor * $node_usd_value;
$display_output = number_format($euro_value_live,2);
```

That should be all, just tried it and I am getting the following to display. My computed field is called "EUR Value (Live)":

[image]

Hope this does the trick for you!

Comment: Is exactly what I was trying to do!Thank you a lot again!